# How to round up the number in c#

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

How can I round up values like this:

```
1.001 => 2
3.3 => 4
```

Means if the number has fractional part than i want the smallest integer number greater than the number ?

I used `Math.Ceiling()` but is not helping. How can i do this ?

Comment: in what way is `Math.Ceiling` not working? It should do as you're asking..

Comment: Math.Ceiling is a sharp solution, how are you trying to handle the output

Comment: You need to include code and output instead of pseudo numbers and arrows

Comment: Looking at the answers below, which are actually comments to this Question, [**`Math.Ceiling`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c.aspx) should work pefectly, in case you are using c# :)

Comment: Remember that the type holding your number (called `System.Double` or just `double`) is an **immutable** type. That means the `Ceiling` method can't modify its argument (it is not a `ref` parameter). Therefore, doing `Math.Ceiling(x);` as a statement doesn't change `x`. You have to reassign, like `x = Math.Ceiling(x);` You can also introduce a new variable of course, `var y = Math.Ceiling(x);`.

Answer (score 4):

Math.Ceiling will work. can you tell what its not working ? in term of any errors or returned result.

```
var returnVal=Math.Ceiling(yourValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Math.Ceiling(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx)) method.

> Returns the smallest integer **greater than or equal** to the specified
>   number.

```
    var i = Math.Ceiling(1.001);
    var j = Math.Ceiling(3.3);

    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Output:

> 2
>
> 4

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.Ceiling(value);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

```c#
double x;
x = Math.Ceiling(5.2)   ;//Result; 6
x = Math.Ceiling(5.7)   ;//Result; 6
x = Math.Ceiling(-5.2)  ;//Result;-5
x = Math.Ceiling(-5.7)  ;//Result;-5
```

This is a simple example. How can't you use it? Maybe you miss to assign a variable to

```c#
Math.Ceiling();
```